# Direction of magnetic force on a permanent magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, ferromagnetism

How would one calculate the direction of the magnetic force on a permanent magnet? I have read about the poles of ferromagnets aligning in a magnetic field, so would the magnetic force just create a torque on the ferromagnet until it aligns with the field?

Answer (score 2):

In a homogeneous magnetic field (e.g. deep inside a long solenoid), the magnet will just experience a torque:

$$\vec T = \vec m\times \vec B$$

This leads to an oscillation around the aligned position, which will be damped one way or another, until it becomes finally statically aligned, as you have already stated.

In an inhomogeneous magnetic field however, the magnet will also experience a force.

$$\vec F = (\vec m\cdot \vec \nabla)\vec B$$

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment).

Comment: Thank you. Is that force where the idea of "like poles repel, opposite poles attract" comes from?

Comment: @Akash: exactly! Well, almost. In all likelihood the idea existed before the theory...